# Mono Evaluator class

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm using the Mono Evaluator class to run C# scripts.  If there is a syntax error in the code, the error gets output to the Console.  I would rather have the output returned to a String. I know I can redirect the entire console, but I would prefer to just get the output of the Evaluator.

There is a MessageOutput property which is a TextWriter, but I have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: Do you have a source for this property, since I can't find any info about it here: http://www.go-mono.com/docs/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3aMono.CSharp.Evaluator%2f%2a

Comment: Hmm... could it be that the documentation is not up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Just going to guess here...

Create a new `System.IO.StringWriter` and assign it to `MessageOutput`?

If it works, you can get the contents of the StringWriter via `ToString()`.

Comment: Tried that, but doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I was just looking for an answer too.  Here's what I ended up doing to capture the output (which may or may not be "Error" output, you would need to parse it) in the var `lastOutput`.

The idea is this:

1) Create a new ConsoleReportPrinter and pass in the CustomTextWriter so we can capture the Write/WriteLine calls
 2) Then pass that new ReportPrinter to the Evaluator as part of a new CompilerContext

```
class CustomTextWriter : TextWriter
{
    private string lastOutput { get; set; }
    public CustomTextWriter() { }
    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        lastOutput = value;
        Console.Write(value);
    }
    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        lastOutput = value;
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.Default;
        }
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ReportPrinter r = new ConsoleReportPrinter(new CustomTextWriter());
    evaluator = new Evaluator(new CompilerContext(
                        new CompilerSettings(),
                        r));
    // all evaluations now will pass through our CustomTextWriter
}
```